How can I implement Role Based Access Control in an ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am currently working on improving my Web API skills.
I have tried to implement them using the IdentityRole class as well as the Identity User but I don't seem to get the hang of it. I am honestly not sure what I am even doing wrong.
I have initiated and populated both tables successfully through a DbContext seeder and I have successfully logged in and registered user and correctly input the default value for the role.
These are both of my UsuarioEndpoints that handle both login and registration:
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(NuevoUsuarioDto nuevoUsuarioDto)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
            return BadRequest("Invalid Input Data");

        var newPersona = await _personaRepo.CreateAsync(nuevoUsuarioDto.ToPersonaFromNuevoUsuarioDto());

        if (newPersona == null) 
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error 500");

        var newUsuario = new Usuario
        {
            UserName = nuevoUsuarioDto.Username,
            Email = nuevoUsuarioDto.Email,
            PersonaId = newPersona.Id
        };

        var usuarioCreado = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUsuario, nuevoUsuarioDto.Password);

        if (!usuarioCreado.Succeeded) 
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error 500");

        var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUsuario, "Admin");

        if (!roleResult.Succeeded) 
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error 500");

        return Ok("User Registered successfully");
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error 500");
    }
}

And this is the login method:
[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
            return BadRequest("Invalid Input Data");

        var usuario = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == loginDto.Username);

        if (usuario == null) 
            return Unauthorized("Invalid Username or Password");

        var checkPassword = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(usuario, loginDto.Password, false);

        if (!checkPassword.Succeeded) 
            return Unauthorized("Invalid Username or Password");

        var token = await _tokenService.CreateToken(usuario);

        Response.Cookies.Append("auth_token", token, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false, // Use true in production with HTTPS
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                });

        return Ok(new { Message = "Login successful" });
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error 500");
    }
}

Now I have tested both and they seem to be working correctly. The context also works correctly. So there doesn't seems to be a problem.
I have used JWT to handle and safely store the roles of the user like so:
public async Task<string> CreateToken(Usuario usuario)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario.UserName)) 
        throw new ArgumentException("UserName is required.");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario.Email)) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Email is required.");

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, usuario.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, usuario.UserName),
    };

    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(usuario) ?? new List<string>();

    foreach (var role in userRoles)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }

    var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds,
                Issuer = _config["JWT:Issuer"],
                Audience = _config["JWT:Audience"]
            };

    try
    {
        var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        throw;
    }
}

The token or JWT rather gets created and send back to the client correctly.
Yet when I try to invoke it through the use of the [Authorize(Roles = "")] attribute, it just doesn't work at all.
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/test/")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Ok("Reached");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("client")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Cliente")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestClient()
    {
        return Ok("This was a client");
    }

    [HttpGet("admin")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestAdmin()
    {
        return Ok("This was an Admin");
    }
}

Now I understand there's probably something else to be done that I am not doing. And there's probably something else to be done or configured within my program.cs. But what? What else do I need in order to correctly handle protected routes within my API?
This is the whole program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnet/openapi
builder.Services.AddOpenApi();
//For relationships
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenServices, TokenServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPersonaRepository, PersonaRepository>();

// Register DbContext with PostgreSQL
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

// Authentication / authorization and JWT config
// In order to create and add to the program the identities
builder.Services.AddIdentity<Usuario, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
    options.DefaultForbidScheme =
    options.DefaultScheme =
    options.DefaultSignInScheme =
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:SigningKey"] ?? "")
        ),
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapOpenApi();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I have tried redoing the program multiple times yet I can't seem to find the issue it all works correctly its just the attribute or the checking of the JWT that doesn't seems to be working.
In case it's necessary, I will also share my DbContext and the Usuario entity which is just a straight up IdentityUser that I linked up with a one to one relationship to a Persona entity which holds all personal information.
This is my DbContext:
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Persona>().HasData(
                new Persona
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Nombre = "Ismael",
                    ApellidoPaterno = "Moron",
                    ApellidoMaterno = "Pedraza",
                    Carnet = "12597382",
                    FechaNacimiento = DateOnly.Parse("1997-10-28"),
                    UsuarioId = "1"
                }
            );

        var hasher = new PasswordHasher<Usuario>();

        builder.Entity<Usuario>().HasData(
                new Usuario
                {
                    Id = "1",
                    UserName = "ismael",
                    Email = "ismaelmp997@hotmail.com",
                    PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "123456"),
                    PersonaId = 1
                }
            );

        List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>
            {
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name="Admin",
                    NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
                },
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name="Cliente",
                    NormalizedName = "Cliente"
                }
            };

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(roles);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Configure one-to-one relationship between Usuario and Persona
        builder.Entity<Usuario>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Persona)
                .WithOne(p => p.Usuario)
                .HasForeignKey<Usuario>(u => u.PersonaId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Optional: cascade delete if needed
    }

    public DbSet<Persona> Personas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings =>
                warnings.Ignore(RelationalEventId.PendingModelChangesWarning));
    }
}

My Usuario model class:
public class Usuario : IdentityUser
{
    public int? PersonaId { get; set; }
    public Persona? Persona { get; set; } = null!;
}

As you can see it's just a simple DbContext. The idea of this project was to create for me a boilerplate that will serve as guidance into implementing a "complete" role-based access control with the use of the tools that Entity Framework Core provides such as IdentityRole and IdentityUser.
I understand that I could've just updated my model to also handle a role property and have it be checked in the relevant endpoints but I do not believe that is the most clear and visually appealing way to do so.
Any guidance, advice or resources into handling this specific problem or any other that might be present within my simple API would be most appreciated.
Thank you for your time.
